# inheriting python method with a call to super inside the method

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am developing a system, which has a series of single multilevel inheritance hierarachy. one of the methods (applicable to all the classes) has to perform the same thing for most of the classes, which is to pass a list to its parent class.

I know that if one doesn't define a method in one of the inherited classes, its parents' methods are used. But when we use the `super` method, we need to mention the name of the class being called.

One method I know to achieve this is to redefine the method at every class with class name as argument. Is there any elegant method where I can define it once at the topmost parent, and then override it only when necessary?

The implementation right now looks like this

```
class a(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myL = list()
        print 'hello'


class b(a):

    def __init__(self):
        super(b,self).__init__()

    def resolve(self, passVal):
        print passVal
        self.myL.append(passVal)
        super(b,self).resolve(passVal+1)


class c(b):

    def __init__(self):
        super(c,self).__init__()
    def resolve(self, passVal):
        print passVal
        self.myL.append(passVal)
        super(c,self).resolve(passVal+1)
```

Instead if I can define resolve in `class a`, and then all other classes inherit the method from it. I understand a will never be able to use it. but redefining the method seems a lot unnecessary extra work.

Comment: If I understand what you are after here, why do you feel like you need to call super everywhere? since the `__init__` args do not change, you don't need to call super on subclasses `__init__`. Also you can have the `resolve` method  in the base class shared by all instances of the subclasses.

Comment: @salparadise, the issue is the lsit at each level need to be updated,also multiple classes may inherit a single clss, and then that class need to contan values from all of its child class values

Comment: `super` is not used for calling the parent method, it is parent or sibling.

Comment: @AmrithKrishna then make a class level attribute and not an instance level attribute. The way your example shows it, this will only update the instance attribute by __one__ instance.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - So how exactly one can call the parent class, assuming that there is only single inheritance

Comment: @salparadise - its not a class attribute, these entries will changed every now and then. Also do understand that there are going to be hundreds of classes (for its own valid reasons), where each a single class may have multiple children (not toehr way round), where it collects item entries from differnet of children, remove some and then pass it to its parent and this continues so on, till topmost class instance is encountered

Comment: Assuming single inheritance, `super` **does** call the ancestor method. However, in multiple inheritance it can do fancy things.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - But that takes us to the original question, that for every class  I need to redefine my method resolve, because in super(), the first argument is the class name. Is there any other way around where I need to define resolve only once?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, - Thanks a lot for the patience and time you are spending to understand the problem

Comment: Again, I do not follow you, what would that `resolve` do exactly in that case

Comment: @salparadise - Thanks a lot for the patience and time you are spending to understand the problem

Comment: all your methods do a different thing: they append a different number to the list and call a different super method. As this is now, this is just some "hypothetical code", and not the real code and the real problem.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - In my problem, every class instance will have a seperate list called 'myL'. Now child classes need to pass entries in its list to the list of its direct parent. this chain goes all the way back upto topmost class instance. The chain needs to be followed, I cant directly update the topmost parent. so all the parents in the chain needs to be called one after the other

Comment: super calls ancestor or sibling method; if you do not define the method in `b`, then the method of `a` gets called from `c.resolve`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I need C to pass its value to b's myL, and b to pass the value to a's myL

Comment: This seems an odd use of inheritance.